# how to extract relevent fields from random form

Tags: php

I have a script that collects data from forms around the internet (JavaScript based)
Now the info is usually name,email,phone. Now I get in my db the name of the field as it was on the site, 
so it is not necessarily 'first_name,','last_name', etc. It could be '_FFE3_main_first_name', etc.
So I'm trying to extract that info but not much success
I tried

```
    foreach($data as $key => $val){
    if(strpos($key, "first")){
        $info["first_name"] = $val;
    } elseif(strpos($key, "last")){
        $info["last_name"] = $val;
    } elseif(strpos($key, "name")){
        $info["name"] = $val;
    } elseif(strpos($key, "mail")){
        $info["mail"] = $val;
    } elseif(strpos($key, "phone")){
        $info["phone"] = $val;
    }
}
```

but I only get 'name', even that first and last exist
I also tried

```
    foreach($data as $key => $val){
    if(strpos($key, "first") && !isset($info["first_name"])){
        $info["first_name"] = $val;
    } elseif(strpos($key, "last") && !isset($info["last_name"])){
        $info["last_name"] = $val;
    } elseif(strpos($key, "name")){
        $info["name"] = $val;
    } elseif(strpos($key, "mail")){
        $info["mail"] = $val;
    } elseif(strpos($key, "phone")){
        $info["phone"] = $val;
    }
}
```

and still no luck, Thank you.

arry output

```
(
[name] => king
[mail] => a@a.com
```

)

Comment: The correct condition would be `strpos($key, 'first') !== false`.